# Check if Cursor is Visible

Tags: vb.net, cursor, breakpoints

I am using Windows.Forms.Cursor.Hide() to hide/show the cursor to the user.

I'm having problems in a few places and want to set a breakpoint to check the state of the cursor --> either hidden or shown.

Is it possible to place a watch on the cursor to check if its hidden at that current time?

Comment: you do know that hiding the mouse pointer may not prevent the form from getting mouse events, right?

Comment: yes, they will be able to click on buttons but should not see their mouse

Answer (score -1):

Use a Field to store the state of Cursor.

```
Private _IsCursorVisible As Boolean = True

Private Sub HideCursor()
   Me.Cursor.Hide()
   _IsCursorVisible = False
End Sub

Private Sub ShowCursor()
   Me.Cursor.Show()
   _IsCursorVisible = True
End Sub
```

Call these Methods to show or hide the cursor

So now you have state of Cursor stored in a Field. Now add a Watch on _IsCursorVisible.

Comment: This does not work since my cursor is being shown even when the value is false. I want to know the exact place that the cursor changes states